# how do I slice a list of lists into separate columns?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp

I think I'm basically trying to do the opposite of concatenation...Here, I have a list of lists and I want them to be separated into different columns, such as Column 1, Column 2...until Column 10 with each column holding different attributes.

What I have currently:

```
['1', 'Her', 'her', 'XX', '_', '_', '3', 'XXXX', '_', '_']
['2', 'hat', 'hat', 'XX', '_', '_', '4', 'XXXX', '_', '_']
['3', "'s", "'s", 'XXX', '_', '_', '3', 'XXX', '_', '_']
['4', 'color', 'color', 'XX', '_', '_', '8', 'XX', '_', '_']
['5', 'was', 'was', 'XX', '_', '_', '0', 'XXX', '_', '_']
```

What I need (starting with column labels on top):

```
['ID, 'Form', 'Lemma'....]
['1', 'Her', 'her',...]
['2', 'hat', 'hat',...]
```

I want to make a separate column for each of the above ten attributes so that I can compare one column from one file (predicted relations) to the same column in another file (goldlabel relations). This is to evaluate a dependency parser.

I've tried the following, but I'm getting an error pointing to the first line of code below:

```
sep_lines = file_pred[0].str.split(" ", n=10, expand=True)

## Making seperate columns for each element such as ID, Form, Lemma etc ##

lines["ID"] = sep_lines[0]

##Error##

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the first code block? So far it is not a list of lists, but one list per line (there are commas and another pair of brackets missing).

Answer (score 0):

May be like that?

```
lol =  [['1', 'Her', 'her', 'XX', '_', '_', '3', 'XXXX', '_', '_'],
        ['2', 'hat', 'hat', 'XX', '_', '_', '4', 'XXXX', '_', '_'],
        ['3', "'s", "'s", 'XXX', '_', '_', '3', 'XXX', '_', '_'],
        ['4', 'color', 'color', 'XX', '_', '_', '8', 'XX', '_', '_'],
        ['5', 'was', 'was', 'XX', '_', '_', '0', 'XXX', '_', '_']]

col0 = [ l[0] for l in lol ]   # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
col1 = [ l[1] for l in lol ]   # ['Her', 'hat', "'s", 'color', 'was']
```

The columns you may again collect in a second dimension.

Comment: >>>col0 = [ l[0] for l in lol ]   # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']<<< This returns an IndexError: list index out of range :/

Comment: I am afraid, I double-checked my example and it works on my computer. I am using Python 3.10.6.